# TimeWindowAll function not invoked in apache flink

Tags: java, stream, apache-flink

I have a very simple streaming pipeline setup in apache flink, the pipeline works and I was able to apply a processFunction to the input data stream like this:

```
    DataStream<MeasurementData> data = env.addSource(consumer);
    DataStream<MeasurementData> dataProcessed =data.process(new FFT());
    dataProcessed.print();
    dataProcessed.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer011<>(
            "localhost:9092",      // Kafka     broker host:port
            OUTPUT_TOPIC,       // Topic to write to
            new MeasurementDataSchema())  // Serializer
    );
```

Now I'd like to apply a ProcessWindowFunction operating on a windows of a certain time, instead of applying the function for each incoming datapoint. I tried it like this:

```
        DataStream<MeasurementData> dataProcessed = data.timeWindowAll(Time.minutes(5))
       .process(new MyProcessWindowFunction());
```

And the definition of MyProcessWindowFunction():

```
public static class MyProcessWindowFunction extends ProcessAllWindowFunction<MeasurementData, MeasurementData, TimeWindow> {

    public void process(Context context, Iterable<MeasurementData> input, Collector<MeasurementData> out) {
        long count = 0;
        for (MeasurementData data : input) {
            for (int frequencyCounter = 0; frequencyCounter < data.data.size(); frequencyCounter++) {
                matrices[frequencyCounter].addElement(data.u, data.v, data.data.get(frequencyCounter).get(0));
            }
            count++;
            out.collect(data);
        }

    }
}
```

But this function seems to never get invoked. I tried placing print statements in there and also stepped trough the whole program with a debugger. Is there anything I'm missing? Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem: The environment was set to use EventTime instead of processingTime, while my data does not contain any event timestamps.